# Firebase setValue method is taking time

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase in my iOs app.

When I use the `setValue` method for updating node value, it takes around 5-10 secs to update value.

How can I overcome this delay?

Code

```
let shiftReportsRef = Database.database().reference().child(Constants.FireBase().users).child(Constants.FireBase().shiftReports).child(firebaseToken).child(cashierId.stringValue).child(todayDate).child(posPointId.stringValue).child(shiftid.stringValue)

shiftReportsRef?.observe(.value, with: { (peakHoursSnapShot) in
   self.shiftDetails = peakHoursSnapShot.value as? [String: AnyObject] ?? [:]
   let lastUpdated = Date().gmtDateTime(.dateTimeSec)
   self.shiftDetails!["lastUpdated"] = lastUpdated as AnyObject

           if self.hasUpdatedValues == false
            {
                self.updatePeakHoursAndLastUpdateDate(amount, refndedAmount, pymtType, timeSlt)
            }

            self.hasUpdatedValues = true  
 })
```

Comment: We would really need to see your code and what is being written to understand the issue. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay I have added the code, Can you please check

Comment: I copied and pasted this code into a project and it responds instantly. I had to fill in some vars as it's unclear how they are set. However, and per my answer, if you're updating a node within the closure which that closure is also observing you're creating a loop that will appear to delay returning results. The code works so that's not the issue; we now don't know what happening in *self.updatePeakHoursAndLastUpdateDate* and, as a side note, what *shiftReportsRef* as well as  *amount, refndedAmount, pymtType, timeSlt* and *self.hasUpdatedValues* resolves to and how those vars are set.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question is a little unclear as to what the expected outcome is. Let's walk through it...

First shiftReportRef is defined

> let shiftReportsRef =
>   Database.database().reference().child(Constants.FireBase().users).child(Constants.FireBase().shiftReports).child(firebaseToken).child(cashierId.stringValue).child(todayDate).child(posPointId.stringValue).child(shiftid.stringValue)

then an an observer is added to that ref. The observer is .value which will observe any changes to that node and return them in a snapshot via an event

```
shiftReportsRef?.observe(.value
```

But then when the first event occurs and the code within the closure executes, the data at that location is overwritten

```
shiftReportsRef?.setValue(self.shiftDetails)
```

which then causes another .value event to fire, therefore overwriting the node again (I think you can see where this is going). Over and over.

So this isn't exactly an answer because we don't know the expected outcome but that's probably why there are delays in the app.

Comment: @Rahish See my comment to the question but as it sits, your code works for me and I cannot duplicate the issue with that code. I still think the node may be updated within the closure which is causing a loop and a perceived delay in returning results.

Comment: At my End due to bool variable its not causing Loop

Comment: @Rahish I don't understand that comment. What I was stating is that if *self.updatePeakHoursAndLastUpdateDate* updates the the same node that *shiftReportsRef* points to, you're going to get a loop and that's what is causing the delay.